# Getting keys as Combobox selected items in Dictionary bind

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I have a `Dictionary` binded with `ComboBox`. For example let's say the `Dictionary` has data set like this:

```
{1,item1}
{2,item2}
```

Now when you select any of the option the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` should get only the integer key not the value.

Here is the code:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> newDict { get; set; }
newDict = MTMInteraction.getPlanId();
txtPlanId.ItemsSource = newDict;
```

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="txtPlanId" ItemsSource="{Binding newDict}" IsEditable="True" Margin="-2,0,79,3" Text="Enter  ID" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

Comment: 22 questions and not a single accepted answer.  Not a single answer ahs worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `SelectedItem` use [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties. Set `SelectedValuePath` against `ComboBox` to property that you want to get and bind `SelectedValue` to some property in view model

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="txtPlanId" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding newDict}" 
    ... 
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SomeIntProperty}"/>
```

or in code `txtPlanId.SelectedValue` should give you `Key` part of your `KeyValuePair<int,string>`

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMemberPath="Key"`

More than you asked but it does answer the question (I think)

```xml
<Window x:Class="BindDictionary.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DLBS, Mode=OneWay}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                 SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DLBSkey}"/>   
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace BindDictionary
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private byte? dlBSkey = 1;
        private Dictionary<byte, string> dlBS = new Dictionary<byte, string>() { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 5, "five" } };      
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Dictionary<byte, string> DLBS { get { return dlBS; } }
        public byte? DLBSkey
        {
            get { return dlBSkey; }
            set
            {
                if (dlBSkey == value) return;
                dlBSkey = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DLBSkey");
            }
        }

    }
}
```